# how to print/return loop in custom way? (python/Django)

Tags: python, django

I have a html template. it's search results design shows the results in this way like

```
result1   result2
result3   result4
result5   result6
so on with load more button
```

now i have data in models.py in my django project i want to print the data in such way on my html page. i have tried for loop. but it gives the result like:

```
result1
result2
result3
result4
result5
result6
result7
```

Please suggest any solution to get the result like the following way:

```
result1   result2
result3   result4
result5   result6
so on with load more button
```

Comment: Is it [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) that you want?

Comment: Or you can try pagination. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/

Comment: oops..question is not showing in a way that i post. let me edit it.

Comment: Use a table in html

Comment: Thanks for advicing pagination that will help me for load more button. Please tell the solution of how it should look on page as i want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Bootstrap to change the style of the elements on the HTML.[Bootstrap Document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/).

In render.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    {% for result in results %}
        <div class="col-sm-6" >{{ result }}</div>
    {% endfor %}    
</div>
```

In views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import MyModel

def myView(request):
    # some code
    results = MyModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'render.html', results=results)
```

Comment: Thank you, yup, it has been fixed. you are right bootstrap is the right solution. I was making a mistake of putting the code outside the container div.